# How to configure IDP-initiated login using Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, salesforce, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to configure my Azure AD B2C account to use IDP-Initiated SAML login. I have been able to configure the custom policies to enable Open ID and SAML logins using SP-Initiated logins but am unable to get IDP-Initiated to work.
For reference, I am trying to use Salesforce to login.
I see in [Azures documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider-options?pivots=b2c-custom-policy): "We don't currently support scenarios where the initiating identity provider is an external identity provider federated with Azure AD B2C, such as Active Directory Federation Services or Salesforce. IdP-initiated flow is supported only for local account authentication in Azure AD B2C."
If I am unable to set up IDP-Initiated using Azure AD-B2C is there another service under Azure that would allow me to set this up?

I have tried to edit the custom policies in my Azure AD B2C to include IDPInitiatedProfile to true
     `<Metadata> ... <!-- Added for IDP Initated SSO From the B2C Side --> <Item Key="IdpInitiatedProfileEnabled">true</Item> </Metadata>`
And configured the policy following the template provided here: https://samltestsp.azurewebsites.net/B2CPolicy
I was able to get the test on the provided website to work but it will not work with my salesforce account.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am in a similar situation whereby I want to integrate with a client who uses Azure B2C acting as an SP, and I have a custom SAML solution that I can only use IdP Initiated flow. Did you use some other service?